# SICStus Prolog JIT compiler

Tags: prolog, x86-64, jit, sicstus-prolog

SICStus Prolog 4.3 added a JIT compiler for x86-64 processors.

I have two questions regarding the JIT compiler.

First, where can I find some documentation (papers, notes, or memos) on the capabilities (and limitations, design, and techniques) of the JIT compiler?

And second, can SICStus be directed to emit the x86-64 assembly code produced by the JIT compiler?

Comment: Official doc has some info about JIT https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/pdf/sicstus.pdf (search fro JIT), 4.3.1 Overview... Some statistics and tuning are described...

Comment: I was already aware of the respective parts of the SICStus Prolog manual... I utilized the environment variables for turning the JIT compiler on and off in the micro-benchmarks I did.

Comment: With strace you can see allocation of memory for jitted code (`mmap`s or `mprotect`s with PROT_EXEC flag), and also you can check /proc/PID/maps (or smaps; PID is pid of active SICStus process) and search for memory segments with x (exec) flag. But this information will allow you only to dump jitted code (for example with gdb, breakpointing on mmap/mprotects with PROT_EXEC and watching for writes to segments; [dumping the mem](http://serverfault.com/questions/173999/); possibly disassembling the machine code), but not to find documentation, papers, patents; no direct info on limitations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public information available about the SICStus Prolog JIT implementation.

You can get some information from `perf` in Linux if you follow the instructions in `library/perf/sp_jit_objdump` in the SICStus installation. Among other things `perf` can show the disassembly of the jitted code.